# What's wrong with this regex - something to do with the reluctant quantifier?

Tags: javascript, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

Anyone know why this doesn't work in javascript? (tried using Chrome and Firefox):

```
console.log('"my name is"'.match(/"?(.*?)"?/));
```

Outputs this:

```
[""", "", index: 0, input: ""my name is""]
```

I expected this:

```
[""my name is"", "my name is", index: 0, input: ""my name is""]
```

I'm not interested in alternative approaches to solve the problem, and it's not a complete solution anyway for what I was trying to achieve (which I've now done a slightly different way) - I'm just interested in why the match fails.

I expected the reluctant quantifier to match everything up to, but not including the final quote.  I don't understand why the expression has failed to match anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that everything in your pattern, including the surrounding quotes, is optional.  Meaning it will just as easily match an empty string. So what's going on inside the regex engine?

- The engine tries to match the first `"?`. No problem it matches the first `"` in the string.
- The engine moves on to the next part of the pattern, `.*?`. Well, the zero-length substring following the first `"` matches this so it continues.
- The engine moves on to the last part of the pattern, `"?`. The next character is `m`, so this doesn't match, but that's okay because the last `"` is optional, so it just doesn't get captured.

Therefore the first match is just the first `"`.

Comment: I didn't notice there were 3 quotes at the beginning of my output - not 2 - that should've been my big clue!

Answer (score 6):

Consider

```
> "foo".match(/.*?/)
[""]
```

`?` tells the regex to match as little as possible, and an empty string is the best it can get. Similarly,

```
> "foo".match(/x/)
null
> "foo".match(/x?/)
[""]
```

An optional pattern never fails, and matches either its content or an empty string.

In your example, it matches the quote first, then matches an empty string with `(.*?)` and (another) empty string with `"?`. Since both tests succeed, it doesn't look any further and the result is just a quote.

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression simply can match anything (well, as long as there's no new line).

- `"?` : no constraint (can be empty but won't if possible)
- `.*?` : no constraint at all, can be the whole string or even an empty string
- `"?` : no constraint (can be empty)

The expression hasn't failed to match anything : The first match is `"`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `.*?`, you are actually asking JavaScript to match 0 to infinite matches, but then you are immediately controlling it with `?`, which means non-greedy search. Simply remove the `?` in that, you should be fine.

```
var regEx = /"?.*"?/;
console.log('"my name is"'.match(regEx)[0]);
console.log('my name is'.match(regEx)[0]);
```

This regex will match both the strings, with or without `"`

Comment: *" I'm just interested in why the match fails"*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
console.log('"my name is"'.match(/"?(.*)\"?/));
```

Result :

```
[""my name is"", "my name is"", index: 0, input: ""my name is""]
```

**Explanation of your problem** :

```
REGEX:     /"?(.*)?"?/g
```

Problem with `(.*)?` in your code. It is a type of `repeated capturing group`.

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a
>   capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or
>   use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Since your input is `"my name is"` , with `(.)*` it will capture `"my name is"` ,

But in the case of `(.*)?` , since it is repeated capturing ,  it will capture only the last iteration , that is `"` .

Refer **[Repeating a Capturing Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)** for more details.

Comment: Quoting the OP: _I'm not interested in alternative approaches to solve the problem [...] I'm just interested in why the match fails._

Comment: I updated my answer. You will get the reason , i hope.